# Android ViewPager, content between tabs and fragments

Tags: android, tabs

Hi i have a main_activity.xml like this

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 

    />
```

I've created a tab-application with the eclipse wizard, which works fine.

But now i want to add a progressbar between the tabs and the content (fragments) which should always be visible. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it, my solution:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="huhu" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

the TextView  is now displayed between tabs and fragments

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the progressbar above the viewpager in the activities xml.

Comment: the main_activity.xml is the xml file of my MainActivity, i don't know where to place it there

Comment: I see. Well, I think you have to modify the xml. For example, the root layout can be a linear layout with vertical orientation, the first view in it can be the progressbar, the second is the pager, that you can find by its id in your activity.